# Which ubuntu server should we setup for the office?

Tags: server

Let's say we are a medium sized company (aim for 50-150 people). We want to be able to setup a ubuntu server with:

1. email server
2. file sharing
3. share printer
4. VPN
5. firewall
6. (optional) cloud? (wonder what you can do with it)

What hardware and software do we need and how should we approach it?

I am sure someone has done it before and want to know how it is usually setup. Any expert can advice? TYIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html).
- Use a LTS release, you don't want to be upgrading every 6 months.
- Hardware needs will vary greatly depending on how your users use the service. Measure your current usage to get an idea for how much hardware you'll need.
- This is a lot for a single server to do. Consider creating a virtualisation host using KVM (and virtual-machine-manager) then spinning up a VM for each service - this will allow you to migrate your services one by one and grow/shrink your resources as needed
- Build two identical servers. One will be the hot spare in case the other one fails.

Some additional links that may be useful:

- http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-setup-ubuntu-business-box-server-ubb-part-1
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SmallBusinessServer
- http://www.zentyal.org/ (Ubuntu-based business box distribution)

Comment: hmm... how much should I spend on buying a hardware, any recommendation? i was planning to use a raspberry pi to do it. But it sure would be slow.

Comment: I've seen a raspberry pi do some crazy things, but I wouldn't want to trust one with the productivity of an entire office. If you go down the virtual host route you'll want plenty of RAM, minimum 8gb and 16-32 is probably more reasonable. None of what you are doing is particularly CPU intensive so a quad-core is probably reasonable. Then just buy enough disk to hold all your data. As a very rough guide, two low-end servers around the US$2000 region is probably a reasonable baseline. Try to ensure you can upgrade memory and disk later if necessary.

Comment: My bad, I mean raspberry pi for testing purposes. However, I don't think it is good enough. If you have to buy a server, where would you get one for testing? Sorry for being newbie.

Comment: A pi will probably be fine as long as you don't expect to put all your data on it or have more than say 10 users connected. You can buy a real entry-level server from any the major vendors (think HP, Dell, Cisco etc) fairly cheaply as well, or take an old desktop lying around / off ebay and test on that.